# Bluetooth and wifi get switched on and off together

Tags: 12.04, wireless, bluetooth, broadcom, inspiron

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with GNOME on a Dell Inspiron 1470, my wlan card is a Broadcom BCM4312. Was previously using Windows 7.

Now at startup both BT and Wifi are switched on. If I switch off bluetooth, wifi automatically does so. When I try the Fn command, f2 in this case, both adaptors switch either on or off.

Is there a way to get them to work independently once again?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me on a Dell XPS 17 L702X (it was also reported to work with Dell XPS 13 and Dell XPS 15 and maybe it works for you too). Open a terminal and copy/paste these commands:

```
echo "#fix dell wifi/bluetooth:" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist dell_laptop" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then restart the laptop.

From here: [Fix Dell XPS 13 Backlight Brightness Not Adjustable And Trackpad Not Working Properly In Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/fix-dell-xps-13-backlight-brightness.html)

Comment: Thanks man, but now I'm running 12.10 and bluetooth is not even recognized, so different problem now haha